# Error on starting the application deployed in WAS7.0

Tags: java, websphere-7

I have deployed a war file in Websphere 7.0 console . Deployment was successful . On starting the application throws error as " Failed to Start "

Error logs are as below.

```
[9/19/11 12:50:36:679 EDT] 0000001f CompositionUn A   WSVR0190I: Starting composition unit WebSphere:cuname=EPROVIDER in BLA WebSphere:blaname=EPROVIDER.
[9/19/11 12:50:36:694 EDT] 0000001f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: Starting application: EPROVIDER
[9/19/11 12:50:36:694 EDT] 0000001f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0204I: Application: EPROVIDER  Application build level: Unknown
[9/19/11 12:50:37:038 EDT] 0000001f ApplicationMg E   WSVR0101W: An error occurred starting, EPROVIDER
[9/19/11 12:50:37:038 EDT] 0000001f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: EPROVIDER
[9/19/11 12:50:37:038 EDT] 0000001f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0220I: Application stopped: EPROVIDER
[9/19/11 12:50:37:038 EDT] 0000001f CompositionUn E   WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=EPROVIDER in BLA WebSphere:blaname=EPROVIDER failed to start.
[9/19/11 12:50:37:038 EDT] 0000001f MBeanHelper   E   Could not invoke an operation on object: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=L67695M1Node02,version=7.0.0.11,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=L67695M1Node02Cell,spec=1.0 because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to give us more info pal.

If you provide us with the full console log, we could surely help.

You can find the log of the server here :
C:*Your installed directory*\IBM\SDP75\runtimes\base_v7\profiles*YourProfile*\logs*yourServerName*
and the file is startServer.log.

You can also try this :

1. Stop the server.
2. Manually delete temp and wstemp directories under your profile directory.
3. Clean publish.

Good luck